# MySQL Workbench -- Create Model with Queries

Tags: mysql

I'm new to using Workbench (obviously) and have hit a wall already.  How do I create a Model using queries?

All the tutorials I've found require me to entire the fields one-by-one and select data type.  I just want to use standard CREATE TABLE etc. queries to build the model quickly.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Of course figured out a way right after posting (after hours of failure).  Reverse engineer worked.  Created everything directly in localhost with queries, then reverse engineered and applied to the model.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help others looking for the same thing, please post the solution you found as an answer (well, at least if SO lets you. I don't remember the rep requirements and such)

Comment: @Jakar There are no reputation restrictions for answering your own question (see ["Can I answer my own question"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer))